# Windows 10 doesn't work in Ubuntu/Windows10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I've been running Windows 10 for a while and thought that a dual boot would be something I'd like to try. To make a long story short, I messed something up *hard* and don't know what to do.

I can boot into grub just fine, but trying to boot into Windows throws me to the recovery page where none of the options work.

I have access to all of my hard drives through Ubuntu. I have tried running Boot-Repair a couple of times and different ways.

Running anything in Windows Recovery doesn't do anything.

Restore, repair, recover, it all does nothing.

I'm just a tech nerd that got himself in over his head, and now just wants to play Overwatch over the weekend.

[image: Picture of the screen I get]
<sup>**Screenshot of the screen I get when trying to boot Windows 10**</sup>

[Boot-Repair Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DPfmQVp8Pg/)

Comment: also worth to note windows DOES have recovery partition as a separate one. so maybe your grub doesn't see windows partition and thats the whole problem. I had the same issue with my windows 10 back in the days when I set that up, but I manually fixed it, eventually. Try to boot up ubuntu live CD and check gparted for your windows partition. If it's still there, all you need is to add grub entry to it.

Comment: What happens when you click "Continue" on that "Choose an option" screen?

Comment: See line 655 in report. You have Windows fast start up on, which is hibernation. The Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated NTFS and grub will not boot it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Note that some updates from Windows will turn it back on.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann It reboots and takes me back to Grub

Comment: @oldfred I do have hibernation turned on but how do I fix it, I cant get into windows at *all*

Comment: You should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. And maybe f8 for repair console. If not you need your Windows repair flash drive, you did make one of those?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive You can make that from another Windows system. But just want repair console.

Comment: @oldfred I dont want to wipe my computer. No matter what I do, I cannot boot into windows, Grub or throught Boot menu. Thats whats so boggling, I can get to the repair console its just that when I do, and I do `bootrec /fixmbr` it cant find a file. "Repair System doesnt work and Id like to avoid wipeing and copying over my files, on another note if I select "windows boot UEFI loader sde1" It says `file /efi/boot/bkpbootx64.efi not found`

Comment: Is this the entry in UEFI boot menu you are booting with? `Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager HD(2,GPT,7f0706f2-7df3-4fb6-9dad-e6159983ed71`

Comment: @oldfred So note to self, when diagnosing and loading Rescatux onto a flash drive, select the flash drive and not the boot drive, wiped the entire drive. Sooooo BibleThump monkaS, on the other hand it boots to windows.... RIP

Comment: UEFI or BIOS often make flash drive first drive when rebooting. And then every other drive changes. I have tried booting wrong system & overwritten wrong partition when trying to recover a bad boot. Or you have to pay attention, silly computer does what you tell it, not what you want it to do.